# dax code for count and distinct count measures (or calculated columns)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I hope somebody can help me with some hints for the following analysis. The students may do some actions for some courses (enroll, join, grant,...) and also the reverse - to cancel the latest action. 
The first metric is to count all the action occurred in the system between two dates - these are exposed like a filter/slicer. 
Some sample data :

```
person-id,person-name,course-name,event,event-rank,startDT,stopDT
11, John, CS101, enrol,1,2000-01-01,2000-03-31
11, John, CS101, grant,2,2000-04-01,2000-04-30
11, John, CS101, cancel,3,2000-04-01,2000-04-30
11, John, PHIL, enrol, 1, 2000-02-01,2000-03-31
11, John, PHIL, grant, 2, 2000-04-01,2000-04-30
```

The data set (ds) is above and I have added the following code for the count metric:

```
       evaluate 
 sumx(
   addcolumns( ds
        ,"z+", if([event] <> "cancel",1,0)
        ,"z-", if([event] = "cancel",-1,0)
        )
    ,[z+] + [z-])
  }
```

The metric should display : 3 subscriptions (John-CS101 = 1 , John-PHIL=2).

There are some other rules but I don't know how to add them to the DAX code, the cancel date is the same as the above action (non-cancel) and the rank of the cancel-action = the non-cancel-action + 1.

Also there is a need for adding the number for distinct student and course, the composite key . How to add this to the code, please ? (via summarize, rankx)

Regards,
Q

Answer (score 0):

This isn't technically an answer, but more of a recommendation.

It sounds like your challenge is that you have actions that may then be cancelled. There is specific logic that determines whether an action is cancelled or not (i.e. the cancellation has to be the immediate next row and the dates must match).

What I would recommend, which doesn't answer your specific question, is to adjust your data model rather than put the cancellation logic in DAX.

For example, if you could add a column to your data model that flags a row as subsequently cancelled, then all DAX has to do is check that flag to know if an action is cancelled or not. A CALCULATE statement. You don't have to have lots of logic to determine whether the event was cancelled. You entirely eliminate the need for SUMX, which can be slow when working with a lot of rows since it works row by row.

The logic for whether an action is cancelled or not moves to your source system (e.g. SQL or even a calculated column in Excel), or to your ETL (e.g. the Query Editor in Power BI) which are better equipped for such tasks. The logic is applied 1 time and then exists in your data model for all measures, instead of needing to apply the logic each time a measure is used.

I know this doesn't help you solve your logic question, but the reason I make this recommendation is that DAX is fundamentally a giant calculator. It adds things up. It's great at filters (adding some things up but not others), but it works best when everything is reduced to columns that it can sum or count. Once you go beyond that (e.g. wanting to look at the row below to adjust something about the current row), your DAX is going to get very complicated (and slow), whereas a source system or the Query Editor will likely be able to handle such requirements more easily.

Comment: Hello Leonard, and thank you for the notes added to my post. Yes, I agree about where is the best place to add the necessary logic. Best regards, Q.